# Clicker game in JS with many clickable images(each has its own counter)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, database, click

I was trying to make an clicker game like [that one](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) but in my game I'd like to have many cookies with their own counter each. I was using the mySQL for store the Name of the cookie, image of it and some other info but now I dont think that store the data in database is the best option. I want to store the data to make my game able to play in multiplayer.

1. Can I store the data in JSON file(strings, images and clicks reached so far)?
2. Do I need to learn the NodeJS and make the game only in that technology ?

Maybe there is better way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the data in a JSON file, but -- except for early prototyping -- this is a worse idea than storing it in MySQL since you will run into performance and reliability issues much earlier. MySQL is not necessarily the ideal data store for your exact needs, but you'll want anything you intend to release to be backed with an actual database of some sort.

Think about the shape of your data: if a player can only have one game state at a time, and states are fairly self-contained, a document store like MongoDB may be more appropriate. Since Mongo stores JSON documents, it's also quite easy to use from Node with drivers like Sequelize. It is, however, less suited to storing data that contains relationships between multiple entities.

Whatever data store you choose, you don't *have* to learn Node. Do you want to? Then do it! If you'd rather build your server with something else, there will almost certainly be a driver for your database.

Comment: ok thank you. I was thinking about learning Node, but now I am pretty sure It will be good for me to know it :).

Comment: I would like to have a object with gobal counter - something like multiplayer game. Is it good to store the amount of clicks to each object as a field(number of counts) in Database ?

This is my idea because I cant find any solution on the web at the moment.